# sqllite query to count across rows

Tags: sqlite

I create an audit trail to record every change in one of my project databases.

I have a table called DatabaseAudit with the columns and some sample values below.  Type can be "Insert", "Update", or "Delete"

```
Id, Timestamp, Type, RecordId
1, 637052212796419902, Update, 13
2, 637052213295073040, Update, 15
3, 637052213388962058, Update, 22
4, 637052213494632806, Update, 3
5, 637052213604466165, Update, 25
```

When Type = "Insert" or "Update", I record the actual values in a table called TableAudit with the columns below

```
DatabaseAuditId, ColumnName, PreviousValue, NewValue
1, Col1, False, True
1, Col2, , P
2, Col1, False, True
2, Col2, , P
3, Col1, False, True
3, Col2, , M
4, Col1, True, False
4, Col2, , P
5, Col1, False, True
5, Col2, , M
```

I am having a hard time generating a query.  For example, I'd like the count of the number of DatabaseAudit entries where the Col1 new value is "True" and Col2 new value is "P". Which for this example would be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
WITH q1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT Count(*) FROM TableAudit WHERE 
(ColumnName = 'Col1' AND NewValue = 'True') OR
(ColumnName = 'Col2' AND NewValue = 'P')
Group by DatabaseAuditId
)

SELECT count(*) FROM q1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS MatchCount
FROM (SELECT id
      FROM DatabaseAudit AS d
      JOIN TableAudit AS t ON d.Id = t.DatabaseAuditId
      WHERE (t.ColumnName, t.NewValue) = ('Col1', 'True')
         OR (t.columnName, t.NewValue) = ('Col2', 'P')
      GROUP BY d.Id
      HAVING count(*) = 2);
```

```
MatchCount
----------
2
```

Answer (score 0):

For each `DatabaseAuditId` with `ColumnName = 'Col1' and NewValue = 'True'` check if there is a row with the same `DatabaseAuditId` and `ColumnName = 'Col2' and NewValue = 'P'` with `EXISTS`:

```
select count(*) counter
from TableAudit t
where t.ColumnName = 'Col1' and t.NewValue = 'True'
and exists (
  select 1 from TableAudit
  where DatabaseAuditId = t.DatabaseAuditId and ColumnName = 'Col2' and NewValue = 'P'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rKaHi21XoFg6on54fcFzDR/0).
Results:

```
| counter |
| ------- |
| 2       |
```